# Magento-Gmail SMTP giving TLS error

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.6

I have installed SMTP Pro extension in my site. I am using Gmail server to send mails. On doing Run test, I am getting the following error message.

SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: XXXXXX.com from: XXXX.com. Unable to send test email.
Exception message was: Unable to connect via TLS
Please check the user guide for frequent error messages and their solutions.
Default templates exist.Email communications are enabled.

My site uses PHP version 5.6. Openssl is also enabled.

I am facing this error after installing SSL for the site.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Did you gave access permission from your gmail

Comment: Check where this errors comes from. It is either, because your server can't connect to google or HTTPS doesn't work. I bet it is the first. It might be, because your machine doesn't like the cert format or encoding, hashing or encryption algorithm. Might be everything and is better for stackoverflow, because it has nothing to do with magento and the people over there are used to such problems I guess.

Comment: Yes. I have granted the application to connect to the Gmail server.